# If Statement not working on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, calculator

I recently tried to make a calculator in Python but the options that I am trying to make with the if statement is not working, if you could pleas tell me what is wrong I would appreciate it, the code is below as follow. Yes I know there is typos I just was needing some help on why this if statement is not working because I have used them before and it worked

```
#Calculator Testing in Pytho 2.7

f == raw_input("""What function would you like to use?
You can type Opt to see the options"""

if f == "Opt":
    print
    """You can choose from the following options when at the 
    function selection screen;
    Type /Add for Addition
    Type /Sub for Subtraction
    Type /Div for Division
    Type /Multi for Multiplication

    Type /menu to go back to the function selection screen
    or
    Type /quit any time to end the program"""

if f == "no":
    print "test"



funcopt = raw_input("What would you to do?")

if funcopt == "/quit":
    print "test"
```

Comment: Explain what do you mean by "not working"

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `f == raw_input(...)` Isn't going to do what you want. How are you running this code? Online interpreter? local IDE? Running a .py file from the command line? pasting into a REPL?

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong in your sample code.  `f == raw_input()` will do a test, and you won't save the result of the test anywhere.  Also, your `raw_input(...` call doesn't have a closing `)` - I assume that's a typo, or you wouldn't even get to the script running.

Answer (score 7):

Your `if` statement works. It is your *`print` statement* that doesn't work:

```
print
"""You can choose from the following options when at the 
function selection screen;
Type /Add for Addition
Type /Sub for Subtraction
Type /Div for Division
Type /Multi for Multiplication

Type /menu to go back to the function selection screen
or
Type /quit any time to end the program"""
```

That string definition is a separate line altogether and *ignored by Python*. Python simply prints an empty line instead.

Start the string on the same line at least:

```
print """You can choose from the following options when at the 
function selection screen;
Type /Add for Addition
Type /Sub for Subtraction
Type /Div for Division
Type /Multi for Multiplication

Type /menu to go back to the function selection screen
or
Type /quit any time to end the program"""
```

Comment: Or if the asker is married to their existing formatting, they could open a bracket on the same line as print and then close it after the string.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some code-braking syntax errors, there. Untested, but try this:

```
f = raw_input("""What function would you like to use?
You can type Opt to see the options""")

if f == "Opt":
    print """You can choose from the following options when at the 
    function selection screen;
    Type /Add for Addition
    Type /Sub for Subtraction
    Type /Div for Division
    Type /Multi for Multiplication

    Type /menu to go back to the function selection screen
    or
    Type /quit any time to end the program"""

if f == "no":
    print "test"

funcopt = raw_input("What would you to do?")

if funcopt == "/quit":
    print "test"
```

`=`  assigns a value to a variable, `==` compares values. [This](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) might be useful